# Ez Publish survey form result format on Email

Tags: php, email, ezpublish

I am sending the result of the survey form in my email. but it has unnecessary lines of comments. I want to omit those lines of comments.. any idea?

here's the sample of the result sent on my email.

```
The following information was collected:
1. How did you Initiate this technical support transaction? (Phoned the Technical Support Hotline):
<!-- START: including template: design/standard/templates/content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl (design:content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl) -->
    No
<!-- STOP: including template: design/standard/templates/content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl (design:content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl) -->
1. How did you Initiate this technical support transaction? (Via Web-Support):
<!-- START: including template: design/standard/templates/content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl (design:content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl) -->
    No
<!-- STOP: including template: design/standard/templates/content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl (design:content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl) -->
1. How did you Initiate this technical support transaction? (Via Email):
<!-- START: including template: design/standard/templates/content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl (design:content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl) -->
    No
```

like this for example 
`<!-- START: including template: design/standard/templates/content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl (design:content/datatype/result/info/ezboolean.tpl) -->`

I don't want to see these comments in my survey form result.. is there a way to omit those?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: the only thing that I do to send the result to my email is put my email in 

`[InformationCollectionSettings] 
EmailReceiver = "myemail@yahoo.com"`

haven't tried any overriding since I'm new to ez publish..

Comment: hello @Epodax.... I happen to change the ContentType to text/html... it omits the comments.. but it's not formatted properly... they are all in one paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have debug mode enabled for your templates.

Try to disable it using this parameter :

https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/site.ini/TemplateSettings/Debug

Comment: It omits all the unnecessary comments.. but the results format goes into 1 paragraph.. I want to format it properly.. is there a way?

Comment: Looks like you're sending an HTML email without any formatting. Try to add proper html format around your paragraphs.

Comment: the only thing that I did was create a user class content and override the form... after that I collect the info and send the result to my email.. however I don't know how to format the result.

Comment: you have to override the email template probably here : `https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-legacy/blob/master/design/standard/templates/content/collectedinfomail/form.tpl` not sure about that

Comment: sorry : https://github.com/ezsystems/ezpublish-legacy/blob/master/design/standard/templates/content/collectedinfomail/form.tpl

Comment: I look to it.. it is the form.tpl file in collectedinfomail.... it says there that don't edit.. just override... but how can I override that template?

Comment: Many ways to do that. The a simplest way : create a template in your custom design with the same name and path

Comment: so you mean I should rename the form.tpl and create a new form.tpl file in the same location? am I right?